# When using Backbone.View a "parent.apply is not a function" error is returned

Tags: backbone.js

Consider this markup

```
<div id="controls" class="controls">
  <a href="#">Home</a> - 
  <a href="#/get">get</a> - 
  <a href="#/new">new</a>
  <input type="text" val="" id="input">
</div>
```

And this piece of javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  // this is used on my code as root.App,
  // but the code was omitted here for clarity purposes
  var root = this,
  undefined;

  var controller = Backbone.Controller.extend({

    routes : {
      // static
    },
  });

  var view = new Backbone.View.extend({
    el : $('#controls'),
    events : {
      'click a' : 'updateOnEnter'
    },

    updateOnEnter : function(el) {
      alert('sss');
      return this;
    },

    initialize : function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'updateOnEnter');
    },

    render : function() {
       return this;
    }
  });

  new view;
  new controller;
  Backbone.history.start();
)};
```

When `view` is called (with `new view`), Firebug fires this error:

```
parent.apply is not a function
error backbone.js (line 1043): child = function(){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); };
```

Any ideas to why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Never mind.

The problem is on line 16 of the above js code:

```
var view = new Backbone.View.extend({
```

it **should** instead be:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
```

*I'm not deleting this question since somebody may find it useful.* The pitfalls of not coming from a CS background, I guess.

Comment: I did. It's a silly mistake but I made it, yayyy :D Thanks for posting this!

Comment: I've lost an hour searching the bug... plz don't remove it :D

Comment: I did the same mistake! Google led me straight to this post ;) Thanks.